# What is the python code to create a column out of a series

Tags: python, pandas

This is such a dumb question, but I don't use python and I'm trying to figure this out.I have a spreadsheet of 70,000 rows. Each row has a column which has something like the following:

```
[{'matchedAddress': '1924 S UTICA AVE, TULSA, OK, 74104', 'coordinates': 
{'x': -95.967224, 'y': 36.134724}, 'tigerLine': {'tigerLineId': '166442756', 'side': 'R'}
```

how do i create code to grab the coordinates information? Basically I need a column that includes the coordinates?

Comment: can you show your python code so far? and if you have your excel in a dataframe `print(df.head(5))` and paste it here

Answer (score 0):

Without giving your code or desired answer it is hard help.

This should work.

```
data={'matchedAddress': ['1924 S UT04ICA AVE, TULSA, OK, 741'],
'x':[' -95.967224'], 'y': ['36.134724'], 'tigerLineId': ['166442756'], 'side': ['R']}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df
```

If it doesnt, as a bare minimum, please share your expected output.